# Solve the diff equation with 2 absolute values

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> $dy/dx = (y-1)/x$

I get up to

$\ln(|y-1|) = \ln(|x|) + C$

But then I get

$|y - 1| = C|x| \implies y = \pm C|x| + 1$

So is the answer

> $y = Cx + 1$

Or

> $y = C|x| + 1$

I am not sure, but I think $y = C|x| + 1$ should be correct, since there is no  reason to remove the absolute value?

Answer (score 1):

It is just $Cx+1$ because $\int\frac{1}{x}\text{d}x=\ln|x|+C$ make the domain of the anti derivative and the derivative the same. Once we get rid of the logs we also get rid of the absolute value. You could have also seen this yourself by plugging in the function back into the equation